# In Excel, how to set one cell equal to not just the value of another, but also with the same fill color?

Tags: excel

I have a table of all of the characters from a game I enjoy playing. Each character has a rarity (Common, rare, epic, or legendary) and I have based the fill color of the row containing the character and its statistics on the rarity manually (so without formulas or anything). I want to create another copy of the table whose values are based on those on the original copy. I used =A1 (for example), which copies the character name correctly, but removes the fill color. How can I set a cell equal to the value and fill color of another?

Comment: With VBA you can do something like this, but why bother? A more robust solution is to use a consistent conditional format which reflects the functional relations that you want to emphasize.

Comment: I agree with John on this. Conditional formatting would work best to solve your problem. In fact, solutions using VBA would slow down your work considerably. Making the workbook less responsive.

Comment: @John Coleman What do you mean by "consistent conditional formatting?"

Comment: Conditional formatting is just conditional formatting. By "consistent" my idea was to find a good conditional formatting scheme that is used throughout the whole sheet instead of something ad-hoc which is different in different rows and cells. Decide on the color of each character and implement it with conditional formatting.